# what are the other tools available for editing eps files other than Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, logo, inkscape, cs6

I made a vector logo using Illustrator cs6 in my office, but when I returned back to my home to work on it on Inkscape, it shows nothing, showing the error-- the file is not supported!

to solve this problem, I need Illustrator, but I don't have money to buy it.
I want to use Inkscape or similar products which are open source.
so, my question is:

what are the other tools available for editing eps files other than  Illustrator?

Comment: Just save your file as an AI8 eps and Inkscape should open it. (You'll lose some more advanced editing features though).

Comment: Save as PDF, ai, SVG depending on how "vector" is your file... and sometimes it helps to save in lower versions than your Illustrator CS6. Also this: https://inkscape.org/en/learn/faq/#How_to_open_EPS_files_in_Windows and this http://clownfishcafe.blogspot.ca/2014/05/importing-eps-files-into-inkscape.html

Comment: is there not another program which can copy all the metadata of a CS6 ,ai file & produce it exactly when needed ?plz answer with good references..thanking Scott, go-me

Comment: You can edit them on Corel. Its a little cheaer and also has a subscription plan.

Answer (score 3):

Following vector drawing applications should have pretty good EPS support:

- Adobe Illustrator
- Corel Draw
- Xara Designer Pro
- Affinity Designer

Some vector drawing apps with adequate EPS support

- AutoCAD
- Inkscape

Of these Xara can open atleast v8 ai files with metadata. Unfortunately newer AI files are in a undocumented, possibly encrypted container, inside a PDF file. So while you can get the graphics you lose all illustrator specific stuff.

There has been some attempt in reverse engineering the container. But this is preempted by adobe as they reserve right to changes. I havent tested Xara in a long time, they might have actually reverse engineered the  ai file to some degree.

Answer (score 0):

A 1-month subscription to Illustrator through the Creative Cloud is $29.99. It's not free, but it's not the hundreds of dollars it used to cost. Might be worth it when compared to the time spent trying to find a work-around.